# IntelliJ IDEA code completion show all constructor signatures?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm considering switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA, but there's one thing holding me back: the autocomplete. Eclipse shows me all the information I want from the start whereas IntelliJ holds back some information. The only thing I'm still missing is separate entries in code completion for each constructor signature. And I believe it's pretty weird that's missing since method signatures are done separately.

**My question being, is it possible (am I overlooking something) to get IntelliJ to show separate entries for each signature for constructors WITH documentation, instead of just showing the class name and making you figure out afterwards if you're even in the right place or not.**

Eclipse way of showing (preferred)
[image: eclipse autocomplete]

IntelliJ IDEA way of showing (not preferred)
[image: intellij autocomplete]

Comment: I deleted my answer, as I had totally missed the fact that you already have that turned on. 

Apologies, but I think that's as good as you're going to get. Personally, I think it's cleaner than Eclipse, as it only shows you the info if you want it. If you think you want to use AffineTransform, why do you care about the constructor for Affine3D?

Comment: it may be cleaner, but it doesn't show any info about the class itself, it only shows method signatures. Eclipse gives me actual javadoc and a much better sense of the class I'm about to create an object of. And Eclipse also doesn't require me to use a separate keycombo for finding out signatures afterwards, I can ctrl+space inside the parenthesis. If I try that in IntelliJ my autocomplete keycombo (also ctrl+space) gets blocked so I can't manually call it anymore....

Comment: Fair enough. Then I don't think that what you are looking for is possible. Sorry.

Comment: What's wrong for clicking on the correct signature in "Documentation for AffineTransform" (the panel on the right) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is base on IDEA version 2021.2.2

In the `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion`, check **Show parameter name hints on completion** under **Parameter Info** session.

[image: setting image]

[image: example image]

Combine with `Ctrl + Q`, you can view the javadoc for each constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up (took em long enough to implement though)

Comment: I miss Eclipse where ctrl+space was your buddy in just about any situation :-(

Answer (score 1):

Type the class name and the parenthesis. Inside parenthesis, type `Ctrl+P`. Eg: `new BufferedWriter( <ctrl+P> )`

In fact you can type, `ctrl+P` to get details of any function, not just constructor.

Comment: that's still the hindsight way of doing it, exactly what I'm trying to avoid "instead of just showing the class name and making you figure out afterwards if you're even in the right place or not."

Comment: I think IntelliJ does it cleaner. First you figure out the class, and then you can decide which constructor to use.

Comment: I like to know what kind of constructor I need before I go into creating a specific object (no commitment), plus Eclipse does it better as it doesn't require a whole separate key combination to show method signatures (Eclipse allows ctrl+space basically everywhere)

Comment: There will be a few transition hiccups, but trust me IntelliJ is far better. I am myself a Eclipse to IntelliJ convert :) In the end, choose an IDE that helps you complete the task :)

Comment: IntelliJ is way worse in this one regard. It is almost impossible to read constructor documentation. You have to enter the class after creating the useless Class(). You can press ctrl+p to get the list of parameters but no docs until you have a full constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to show overloaded constructors by enabling a hidden option. Invoke the `Help | Find Action` menu item and type `Registry` to go to the Registry. Here enable the `java.completion.show.constructors` option.
[image: constructor overloads in completion]

Copied From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43639241/2920861