# Show overloads of a method in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Often times I know what method to use but not what overload of that method. Is there a quick way to show all overloads of a method in Intellij?

Comment: Look on the structures tab to the left when you're viewing the object.  Sort method names alphabetically.

Comment: That just shows me methods of the class I'm currently editing, not of the class I want to use.

Comment: Edit the one you want to use.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use [Basic Code Completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html) <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>?
[image: overloads in completion]

It is also possible to show overloaded constructors by enabling a hidden option. Invoke the `Help | Find Action` menu item and type `Registry` to go to the Registry. Here enable the `java.completion.show.constructors` option.
[image: constructor overloads in completion]

When you already have the complete method or constructor name, and just want to know which parameters it and its overloads accepts, use `View | Parameter Info` <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
[image: parameter info]

Comment: I expanded my answer with info on how to enable showing overloaded constructors in Code Completion.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe because it doesn't matter which overloaded constructor you choose, the completion is always the same. Or the feature is not quite finished?

Comment: Big up vote for the java.completion.show.constructors 

Comment: hmm, when I do that, it just autocomplete method name, so in your example it would end with s.replace(oldChar, newChar) :/

Comment: it might be helpful to stress that *Cmd/Ctrl* + *Space* should be pressed before having typed method opening parenthesis, as shown in first picture with `s.replace`

Comment: you are a life saver, now i dont have to go back and forth between classes, im wondering why this is not default setting for Intelij...

Comment: @superjos is there some plugin that shows me once i already have the braces and some args written. i often find myself looking for alternative signatures to call. +1 for eclipse on this so far.

Comment: I'm not able to use the arrow keys to cycle between the options?