# Hide overloads of a method in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

The opposite of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468466/show-overloads-of-a-method-in-intellij). I come from a C# / VisualStudio background, so IntelliJ code completion just seems cluttered with all the overloads. Is there a way to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment, you can vote for the related feature request:

- [IDEA-230901](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230901) Combine autocomplete suggestions for overloaded methods